# How do I get a Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 gigabit ethernet card working?

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I bought a new computer, hoping to dual boot Win 8 and Ubuntu 13.04. 
I have successfully installed both OS, but in Ubuntu I have no connection to the internet, even though the ethernet cable is plugged in and internet works perfectly in Win 8. Already in the Ubuntu installer, it says that I have no internet connection.

Things that might be of interest:

- I have this motherboard: MSI Z87-G45 Gaming (http://www.msi.com/product/mb/Z87-G45-GAMING.html#specification)
- Internet did not work in Win 8 until I installed the networking drivers that came with the motherboard (Killer Ethernet something)
- I have tried different installation configurations, tried v. 13.04, 12.04 and 12.10, and tried installing on a separate hard drive. (the fact that the installer says "no internet connection" seems to indicate that the problem has nothing to do with the installation though.)
- I can't even reach my router at 192.168.0.1.
- The motherboard has no wireless capabilities.
- If I run the terminal command lspci I get the following output (among other things):

> 03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)

I have spent hours and hours googling, trying many different suggested methods and not quite finding someone who seems to be having the same problem.

Comment: If I run the terminal command lspci I get the following output (among other things): 03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)

Comment: check out my reply in ubuntuforums.org

Comment: Thank you! It's late and I need to sleep but I will try that method first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Let me know how it turns out..

Answer (score 4):

I got information from another source that kernel 3.10 had support for this networking card. So what I did was install the kernel using this guide

- http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2013/07/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3101-on.html

> First thing first, you have to download ALL deb files which are
>   appropriate for your system architecture (32bit or 64bit), then put
>   them in same folder for easy process.

Note: This answer is an updated version of the original post:

You need this one for sure:

- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-rc7-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.0-031100rc7_3.11.0-031100rc7.201308252135_all.deb

And then depending on your architecture grab the next 2:

64bit:

- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-rc7-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.0-031100rc7-generic_3.11.0-031100rc7.201308252135_amd64.deb
- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-rc7-saucy/linux-image-3.11.0-031100rc7-generic_3.11.0-031100rc7.201308252135_amd64.deb

32bit:

- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-rc7-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.0-031100rc7-generic_3.11.0-031100rc7.201308252135_i386.deb
- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-rc7-saucy/linux-image-3.11.0-031100rc7-generic_3.11.0-031100rc7.201308252135_i386.deb

> Once downloaded, simply run the following command to install:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

In case, you want to remove this version of Kernel, run this command:

```
 sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.11*
```

Very simple and the connection started working right away after update and restart. I haven't experienced any problems with the new kernel yet so as long as I don't I will stick with this solution. It seems though as the thread you linked to me described the same problem and I'm sure that would've fixed the problem as well.

For those of you who might want to follow the instructions in that thread, on the top of page 7 there is a post from someone who had made a patch for this issue (not sure exactly how it worked but I guess it was to simplify and reduce the manual hacking as described in the first post).

An infinite thank you to all of those who helped me!

Answer (score 2):

According to these posts from [sauyon](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008332&p=12604916#post12604916) and [Mahler122](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008332&p=12046426#post12046426) on ubuntuforums.org you have to compile a kernel module for this network card manually.

Open a Terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. First you need to install some packages that are needed for compiling. Type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fakeroot build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Create a new folder, download the Compat-Wireless sources and extract them:

```
mkdir compat_src
cd !$
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.9-rc2/compat-drivers-3.9-rc2-2-su.tar.bz2
tar xvjf !$:t
cd compat-drivers-3.9-rc2-2-su
```

Download sauyon's patch and test if it works (I posted it on gist.github.com because the [original source](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=241317&d=1365935824) is behind ubuntuforum.org's login page. Hope this is ok):

```
wget https://gist.github.com/Germar/ea11bc1e998fee965f03/raw/5b1d28d42f0d4f2c4bf063002fde126becc61928/alx-patch.txt
patch --dry-run -p1 < alx-patch.txt
```

If there was no error, apply the patch:

```
patch -p1 < alx-patch.txt
```

Than select the driver that should be build, build and install it:

```
./scripts/driver-select alx
fakeroot make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe alx
```

### EDIT: How to do that without working internet:

I just remembered that you have no internet so you can't use apt-get or wget :D. So you need to download everything on an other computer with internet access (or in your Win8 installation) and transfer it with e.g. an USB-Thumbdrive.

In Ubuntu open a Terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get -qq --print-uris install fakeroot build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) | cut -d\' -f 2 > urls.txt
```

Copy the `urls.txt` to your thumbdrive and move over to the other computer. Download all files in urls.txt (if the other computer is running Linux you can use `wget < urls.txt`) and save them in a folder called `deb` on your thumbdrive. Also download [compat-drivers-3.9-rc2-2-su.tar.bz2](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.9-rc2/compat-drivers-3.9-rc2-2-su.tar.bz2) and [alx-patch.txt](https://gist.github.com/Germar/ea11bc1e998fee965f03/raw/5b1d28d42f0d4f2c4bf063002fde126becc61928/alx-patch.txt)

Next move back to your faulty Ubuntu, plug in the thumbdrive, open a Terminal and type:

```
cd /media/YOUR_USERNAME/THUMBDRIVE_NAME
sudo cp deb/* /var/cache/apt/archives/
sudo apt-get install fakeroot build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
mkdir -p ~/compat_src/compat-drivers-3.9-rc2-2-su
cp compat-drivers-3.9-rc2-2-su.tar.bz2 ~/compat_src/
cp alx-patch.txt ~/compat_src/compat-drivers-3.9-rc2-2-su/
cd ~/compat_src
tar xvjf compat-drivers-3.9-rc2-2-su.tar.bz2
cd compat-drivers-3.9-rc2-2-su
patch --dry-run -p1 < alx-patch.txt
patch -p1 < alx-patch.txt
./scripts/driver-select alx
fakeroot make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe alx
```

Answer (score 0):

You could purchase a Realtek Edimax USB WiFi adapter to connect.  These can  be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY).

Comment: Thanks, that is a good alternative. But if possible I would really like to get the ethernet connection working.

Comment: Please see this. No patch is required. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166562&highlight=E2200

Answer (score 0):

I just worked through this and the best solution was found from [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166562&highlight=E2200)

The patch mentioned in the first technique has been merged into the kernel. This means that rather than patch you can load this backport file from [kernal.org](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/ker...3.10-2.tar.bz2), and then simply run:

```
  cd Desktop/backports-3.10-2
  make defconfig-alx
  make
  sudo make install
  sudo modprobe alx
```

It is much simpler than patching.

The first post having problems, that it doesn't detect my *Nvidia* driver