# How do I install a network driver on Linux?

Tags: networking, internet, amd-graphics, lan, msi

I want to use `eth0` driver, but my network card is UNCLAIMED.

I use Killer e2200 Gigabit Ethernet controller.

Please tell me how to install the Networkdriver and how to use `eth0`.

Comment: This is a new OS installation or just hardware change?

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed OS and you want to run Network Card as new hardware, you must ask the vendor for network drivers. Usually network drivers come with source pakage of kernel modules.
You must compile driver module for you kernel.

1. install "build essential" utilites

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```
2. unpack your source pakage to some folder
3. go to this folder
4. do this:

   ```
   $ ./configure
   $ make
   $ sudo make install
   ```

After installation you can load just compiled module by enter command:

```
$ sudo insmod your_module.so
$ ifconfig eth0 up
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest network devices usually take a while to work their way into the Linux kernel. All drivers are usually built into big distributions like Debian (or Ubuntu) and Centos.

The other answer answers here give great detail on how to compile the driver module and insert it - if you look at the Linux source code, you can "grep" your device name in the /drivers/net directory eg.

```
grep -ri e2200 /usr/src/linux*/drivers/net/
```

Or

```
grep -ri killer /usr/src/linux*/drivers/net/
```

It might yield something like:

```
drivers/net/dsa/Kconfig:    tristate "Qualcomm Atheros QCA8K Ethernet switch family support"
drivers/net/dsa/Kconfig:      This enables support for the Qualcomm Atheros QCA8K Ethernet
drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/Makefile:# Makefile for the Atheros network device drivers.
drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/Kconfig:# Atheros device configuration
drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/Kconfig:config NET_VENDOR_ATHEROS
drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/Makefile:obj-$(CONFIG_ALX) += alx.o
drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/Makefile:alx-objs := main.o ethtool.o hw.o
drivers/net/ethernet/qualcomm/Kconfig:    This enables support for the Qualcomm Atheros QCA7000.
drivers/net/ethernet/qualcomm/Kconfig:  tristate "Qualcomm Atheros QCA7000 SPI support"
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/Kconfig: bool "Atheros bluetooth coexistence support"
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/Kconfig: tristate "Atheros 802.11n wireless cards support"
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/Kconfig:   Atheros IEEE 802.11n AR5008, AR9001 and scan support"
drivers/net/wireless/ath/Kconfig:   bool "Atheros/Qualcomm devices"
drivers/net/wireless/ath/Kconfig:     For information on all Atheros wireless drivers visit:
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ar5523/Kconfig:       tristate "Atheros AR5523 wireless driver support"
drivers/net/wireless/ath/carl9170/Kconfig:    This is the mainline driver for the Atheros "otus" 802.11n USB devices.
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/Kconfig:        tristate "Atheros 802.11ac wireless cards support"
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/Kconfig:          Atheros IEEE 802.11ac family of chipsets.
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/Makefile:# Copyright (c) 2004-2011 Atheros Communications Inc.
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/Makefile:# Copyright (c) 2011-2012 Qualcomm Atheros, Inc.
drivers/net/wireless/ath/wcn36xx/Kconfig:     Qualcomm Atheros WCN3660 and WCN3680 mobile chipsets.
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/Kconfig: bool "Atheros 5xxx AHB bus support"
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/Kconfig:   This adds support for WiSoC type chipsets of the 5xxx Atheros
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/Kconfig: bool "Atheros 5xxx PCI bus support"
drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/Kconfig:   This adds support for PCI type chipsets of the 5xxx Atheros
```

I've trimmed some lines for brevity. But the module names are the same as the directory before Kconfig, so you can check if it is active with lsmod:

```
lsmod
```

Sometimes my intel drivers for my onboard Wi-Fi dies, then I have to remove and re-add it:

```
rmmod iwlmvm
modprobe iwlmvm
```

Then magically it works again. I still need to contribute this fix to the NetworkManager project...

If this returns "alx", then the driver is already loaded:

```
lsmod | grep alx
```

If not, you're out of luck. You can manage the interface with the "ifconfig" or "ip link" commands:

```
ifconfig
ip link
```

Newer Linuxes don't use "eth" as interface names any more.

So I grepped my kernel tree for "killer" and "e2200" and couldn't find anything. Then I did a web search, and found out that is is an Atheros device, and similar to the "alx" driver. Someone updated the driver to work with your card, lucky you. If there are enough cards like that out in the world, or he upstreamed it, all you have to do is to update Linux and it will just work.

If not, you will have to compile it yourself, as per [How do I get a Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 gigabit ethernet card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333938/how-do-i-get-a-qualcomm-atheros-killer-e2200-gigabit-ethernet-card-working) from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008332&page=7&p=12604916#post12604916.

Welcome to Linux! No go out and buy some older hardware that someone has already made free drivers for... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please run the command:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0200
```

Is your device 1969:e091? Here are instructions to get your device working. First, I assume you are running Ubuntu 13.04:

```
lsb_release -d
```

If not, stop as these instructions are written for 13.04 only and will have unknown results on earlier Ubuntu versions. These instructions have been tested and are working in 13.10. Get a working wireless connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Now download this to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.10/backports-3.10-2.tar.bz2 Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now back to the terminal:

```
cd Desktop/backports-3.10-2
make defconfig-alx
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe alx
```

Your ethernet should now be working.